# ID field to be prefixed with AB_ (Example: AB_00yyhhgdbdbd)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I'm trying to select specific fields in a hive table and save the result in a text file. The main problem is that, for one of the fields in the table, I want to add prefix in all the rows of a particular column. Currently, all rows of that column in the hive table are in the form `00yyhhgdbdbd`. Now, I want to write my select statement and prefix this row with `AB_` . And in my text file, it will be of the form `AB_00yyhhgdbdbd`). How can I handle this Please?

```
AB_00yyhhgdbdbd
AB_00yyhhgdbdbd
AB_00yyhhgdbdbd
```

Any functions to handle this in hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [concat()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function to concatenate with AB_ in the select

```
select concat('AB_', id) from your_table;
```

As of Hive 2.2.0. you can use [|| operator](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators) instead of concat:

```
select 'AB_'||id from your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin. select concat('AB_', id) from your_table; works. Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL supports column aliases in SELECT statements. For example, say there's a table "people" with the columns "FirstName", "LastName", and "BornOn", and you want to combine the first and last name into a column called "FullName", and don't really like the name "BornOn" so you want to call that "Birthday", you could do that like this:

```
SELECT
  FirstName + LastName AS FullName,
  BornOn AS Birthday
FROM people
```

Comment: Thanks for that @mbrewster. What I'm actually trying to achieve goes way beyond aliases. In hive, I want to prefix an id column with AB_ so that all the rows will be of that form. I.e, If the first row in the column is previously ooyyhh, I want to prefix it with AB_00yyhh so that all the rows of that column will be in that form and save the output in a text file. I'm trying to achieve that in hive.